# How do I center text in a console application?

Tags: c#, console

I am creating a console application and I need to center the text. Is there an easy way to do that, or do I have to place spaces before the text until it is centered? Thank you for your help.

Example, using '|' as the center of the console:
                                        Hello|World

Comment: no, that one doesn't get the exact center, thanks though

Comment: How about posting some example text and where you think the center should be? Because the SO answer Habib posted definitely should do the trick.

Comment: @MonkeyLogik I have no idea what your definition of center is, but multiple answers have been given to you, all of them putting the text exact in the middle.

Answer (score 18):

```
string s = "Hello|World";
Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - s.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Try doing it more than once and you'll notice the issue

Comment: Use `(Console.CursorTop + 1)` to write to the next line

Comment: This is risky, when copy+pasted without safeguards, as this code can cause `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` to be thrown, depending on string- and console width.

Answer (score 9):

First get the center of your console by dividing the `Console.WindowWidth` property by 2. Then you can take it a step further to be more precise; get the length of your string and divide that by 2. Add both of these numbers together and it will center perfect.

```
    string textToEnter = "44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444";
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (textToEnter.Length / 2)) + "}", textToEnter));
    Console.Read();
```

[image]

If your not too familiar with the use of `String.Format()`, take a look at this:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: no, that one doesn't work either. the output is like this:
             Hello World! In the Middle!|
where '|' is the actual center

Comment: @MonkeyLogik Please update your question with HOW your output should look. Your comment doesn't show me anything.