# How do I align Console.WriteLine to the center

Tags: c#

I tried to align the text, so I have a pyramid but I just can't find the solution.

```
Console.Write("Bitte geben Sie die Anzahl der Zeilen der Pyramide ein: ");
int zeilen = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string raute = "#";
string stern = "*";
int anzahlzeichen = -1;
double hilfsvariable = 1;

while(zeilen > 0)
{
    anzahlzeichen += 2;
    int x = anzahlzeichen;

    while(x > 0)
    {
        if (hilfsvariable%2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", stern);
            x--;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", raute);
            x--;
        }
    }

    hilfsvariable += 1;
    Console.WriteLine();
    zeilen--;
}
```

Right now it prints all starting on the left side.

Anybody got an idea about how to align it to the center?

Thank you

Comment: Ah I remember these homework problems... You'll likely want to determine how many space characters to insert at each level.

Comment: Please, next time, can you try to provide code in English?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I center text in a console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917203/how-do-i-center-text-in-a-console-application)

Answer (score 2):

It will wite string in the center:

```
string str = "Hello";
Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - str.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```