# I want to center the text in console both horizontally and vertically using c#

Tags: c#, terminal, console

I want to center the text when my game finishes. Right now it comes on the top and i would like to bring it in the middle of the screen

This is the code i have so far and its output.

```
{
    SoundEffect();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;//Text color for game over

    //Assign string output when game is over, player points and enter key 
    String textGameOver = "Game Over!";
    String playerPoints = "Your points are:";
    String enterKey = "Press enter to exit the game!";

    //Output to show on screen
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (textGameOver.Length / 2)) + "}", textGameOver));
    int userPoints = (snakeElements.Count - 4) * 100 - negativePoints;//points calculated for player
    userPoints = Math.Max(userPoints, 0); //if (userPoints < 0) userPoints = 0;

    //Output to show player score on screen 
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (playerPoints.Length / 2)) + "}", playerPoints + userPoints));

    SavePointsToFile(userPoints);//saving points to files


    //exit game only when enter key is pressed
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (enterKey.Length / 2)) + "}", enterKey));
    while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) {}
    return 1;
}
```

[Current output of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yURil.png)

Comment: Why have you provided code as an image? I find it _really_ hard to debug those. _"The issue I am facing is that ..."_ tells us what you want to do, but doesn't tell us what problems you've had with the snippet you found on [SO].

Comment: Code in an image is unacceptable here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Please [edit] your post to include the actual code as text, properly formatted for readability. There is formatting help available by clicking the `?` button in the answer toolbar when editing.

Comment: Is your issue with getting the vertical centering? You have the code for getting the horizontal start position based on the character width of the string (`s.Width`). How might you get the vertical start position based on the number of rows you wish to print?

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917203/how-do-i-center-text-in-a-console-application) you "refer" to is *the answer* to the question as asked... so I used it as duplicate. You may want to [edit] question to clarify what problems you have implementing advice from that question so it can be considered to re-open (don't forget to show code as text too)

Comment: okay i will add it as code .

Comment: @John yeh the code i am referring to when i tested it brings it to the top, i am confused on how to use that code in my own snake game.

Comment: Centering vertically is the exact same thing as centering horizontally if you think about it. The only difference is that instead of having the string length, you have the number of lines.

Comment: @John i tried understanding what you said and i managed to bring all of them in the centre but they are still at the top center.

Comment: i have added the new code above, how can i bring them to center as shown in the picture ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to state clearly that you're trying to center it both horizontally and vertically, and show a screenshot of what you currently have. Then we can maybe get your question re-opened and I can add an answer.

Comment: @John thank you, i updated as mentioned by you. Please let me know how can i fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to work out where to start printing the lines vertically:

```
private static void PrintLinesInCenter(params string[] lines)
{
    int verticalStart = (Console.WindowHeight - lines.Length) / 2; // work out where to start printing the lines
    int verticalPosition = verticalStart;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        // work out where to start printing the line text horizontally
        int horizontalStart = (Console.WindowWidth - line.Length) / 2;
        // set the start position for this line of text
        Console.SetCursorPosition(horizontalStart, verticalPosition);
        // write the text
        Console.Write(line);
        // move to the next line
        ++verticalPosition;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PrintLinesInCenter("hello", "this is a test", "of centered text");
```

Result:

[image]